# replace selected element with first and move the entire array to next indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am stuck in a scenario where I have to replace the selected element at zero index and shift the other elements to right:

for example:
these are **dynamic arrays (size changes everytime)** but for better understanding I am just giving example:

**example**

data = [{a: 102, b: 202}, {a:234, b:332}, {a:223, b:343}]

selected index= 1

output = [{a:234, b:332},{a: 102, b: 202},{a:223, b:343}]

**index.js**

```
    arrangeArray (data , selected) {
      data = data.splice(0, selected)//selected =1
      //[{a:234, b:332},{a: 102, b: 202},{a:234, b:332},{a:223, b:343}]
}
```

problem with the above code is i can add at first index but can't remove the selected index
any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you try to format your question so that someone else can read it? You even got a preview that you see before you post your question

Comment: @baao  edited  thequest ?

Comment: have you tried array.unshift?

Comment: Do you want to remove an element from a given index and insert it in the beginning of array?

Comment: yes @HassanImam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the simple solution:

```
var copydata = data[selected]
data.splice(0,0,copydata) ///first copy the element
data.splice(selected,1) //cut the elemnt
return data
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{a: 102, b: 202}, {a:234, b:332}, {a:223, b:343}]
//[{a:234, b:332},{a: 102, b: 202},{a:223, b:343}]

function arrangeArray(data , selected) {
      var selectedData = data[selected]
      var firstHalf = data.slice(0, selected)
      var secondHalf = data.slice(selected + 1, data.length)
      var newArray = [...firstHalf, ...secondHalf]
      newArray.unshift(selectedData)
      return newArray
      
      
}

console.log(arrangeArray(data, 1))
```

Hope it may help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove an element from from a given index. `Array#splice` returns the removed element inside an array, store it in a variable and then, using `array#unshift` add the removed element.

The below statement will add `removedElement[0]` at 0 index.

Element can also be added using `array#splice`, `data.splice(0, 0, removedElement[0])`

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

```js
var data = [{a: 102, b: 202}, {a:234, b:332}, {a:223, b:343}];
var index = 1;
var removedElement = data.splice(index, 1);
data.splice(0, 0, removedElement[0]);
console.log(data);
```

```js
var data = [{a: 102, b: 202}, {a:234, b:332}, {a:223, b:343}];
var index = 1;
var removedElement = data.splice(index, 1);
data.unshift(removedElement[0]);
console.log(data);
```